# Terminal vs. Token && Nonterminal vs. Lexeme

Tags: compiler-construction

I was wondering what's the difference between a Terminal symbol and a Token generated in Lexical Analysis, as well as a Non-terminal and a Lexeme.

Seems to me like they are the same thing, but used interchangeably depending on the context of which you use them in.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954721/what-is-the-difference-between-token-and-lexeme

Comment: @BlackBear given that thread, when I say:
assignment => exp '=' exp ... then exp '=' exp is a lexeme of the token called assignment yes?

Comment: @gEdringer No, in that production `assignment` and `exp` are non-terminals and `=` is a terminal. Given the input `x=42+y`, the lexemes would be "x", "=", "42", "+" and "y" and the tokens would be something like `ID("x")`, `EQ`, `INT(42)`, `PLUS` and `ID("y")`.